# Efficiently finding the longest matching prefix string

Tags: python, string, longest-substring

My current implementation is this:

```
def find_longest_matching_option(option, options):
    options = sorted(options, key=len)
    longest_matching_option = None
    for valid_option in options:
        # Don't want to treat "oreo" as matching "o",
        # match only if it's "o reo"
        if re.match(ur"^{}\s+".format(valid_option), option.strip()):
            longest_matching_option = valid_option
    return longest_matching_option
```

Some examples of what I'm trying to do:

```
"foo bar baz something", ["foo", "foo bar", "foo bar baz"]
# -> "foo bar baz"
"foo bar bazsomething", (same as above)
# -> "foo bar"
"hello world", ["hello", "something_else"]
# -> "hello"
"a b", ["a", "a b"]
# -> "a b" # Doesn't work in current impl.
```

Mostly, I'm looking for efficiency here. The current implementation works, but I've been told it's `O(m^2 * n)`, which is pretty bad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, regex should be thrown! You should look at a solution with `str.startswith`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I did have that, but I it doesn't take into account the whitespace. Even if I added a space to each string in the `options` list, I still can't account for the other types of whitespace, or multiple spaces.

Comment: The examples you've given, seem to account for that. In fact something like `max(filter("foo bar baz something".startswith, ["foo", "foo bar", "foo bar baz"]), key=len)` would work nicely.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Example #2 doesn't work with that.

Comment: @naiveai : you might first replace `\s+` with say `,` or a single space in all of your strings, and then use @coldspeed solution (or even more efficiently loop on sorted input and return the first match)

Comment: What's the expected output of `find_longest_matching_option('a b', ['a', 'a b'])`?

Comment: @Rawing `'a b'`, actually. Didn't think of that, and my current impl. doesn't work with that.

Comment: @naiveai Could you help me understand why it doesn't work? Are you trying to match entire words?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, I'm not trying to match words specifically. I just want to be as greedy as possible and grab everything to the point where there's a whitespace followed by a character that doesn't match any of the strings in my list.

Comment: @naiveai Understood. Both of our answers should have sufficiently addressed your problem. If there are any use cases that break, do let me (and Rawing respectively) know.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Rawing I really appreciate both your answers, I'm testing and trying to understand them right now. Will accept in a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. Whosever answer you decide to accept, remember you can upvote them both. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with `foo`.

```
def foo(x, y):
    x, y = x.strip(), y.strip()
    return x == y or x.startswith(y + " ")
```

`foo` returns true either if two strings are equal, or one (plus a space) is a substring of the other.

Next, given a case string, and a list of options, you can use `filter` to find all valid substrings for the given case string, and then apply `max` to find the longest one (see tests below).

Here's a few test cases for `foo`. For the purpose of demonstrating, I'll use `partial` to curry `foo` to a higher order function.

```
from functools import partial

cases = ["foo bar baz something", "foo bar bazsomething", "hello world", "a b", "a b"]
options = [
      ["foo", "foo bar", "foo bar baz"], 
      ["foo", "foo bar", "foo bar baz"],
      ["hello", "something_else"],
      ["a", "a b"],
      ["a", "a b\t"]
]
p_list = [partial(foo, c) for c in cases]

for p, o in zip(p_list, options):
    print(max(filter(p, o), key=len))
```

```
foo bar baz
foo bar
hello
a b
a b
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer mainly because I'm a sucker for functional-esque programming, but Rawing's answer also works correctly as far as I can see, and you should use it if you want a little more straightforward solution.

Comment: @naiveai I'm "partial" to this solution myself, given the core functionality encompasses a whopping 3 lines. Complexity wise, the answers are (probably) the same, but Rawing's may be faster (in terms of the constants in the BigO) because it's a plain loop at C speed.

Comment: Personally, I feel it's exceedingly elegant and fast *enough* for my needs. If I need to go faster I'd definitely go with Rawing's answer.

Comment: By the way, could you suggest a title that I could use so this question is more easily searchable?

Comment: @naiveai FTFY, the title.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is overkill here; you can simply append a space to each string before comparing them to get the same result.

You also don't need to sort the data. It's more efficient to simply loop over every value.

```
def find_longest_matching_option(option, options):
    # append a space so that find_longest_matching_option("a b", ["a b"])
    # works as expected
    option += ' '
    longest = None

    for valid_option in options:
        # append a space to each option so that only complete
        # words are matched
        valid_option += ' '
        if option.startswith(valid_option):
            # remember the longest match
            if longest is None or len(longest) < len(valid_option):
                longest = valid_option

    if longest is not None:
        # remove the trailing space
        longest = longest[:-1]
    return longest
```